# how to fix "cannot return value referencing function parameter 'x' returns a value referencing data owned by the current function" in the async rust?

Tags: rust

I'm new to rust , I write some async code to send two request concurrently:

```rust
use std::time::Duration;
use futures::future::join_all;
use tokio::time::sleep;

// #[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Request {}

impl Request {
    pub async fn do_req(&self , num : i32) -> i32 {
        sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
        num * 2
    }
}

#[tokio::test]
async fn test() {
    let v = vec![Request{} , Request{}];

    let futs : Vec<_> = v.into_iter().map(|req|{
        req.do_req(1)
    }).collect();

    let res = join_all(futs).await;

    println!("{:?}", res);
}
```

but I get a error in the iterator "cannot return value referencing function parameter `req` returns a value referencing data owned by the current function" in the line "req.do_req(1)".

I consider req.do_req(1) return a new value so I can't understand why the error arise, it's very kind if someone can tell me how it is happened and how to fix it,thank you.

Comment: Note that `join_all()` takes an iterator, so you don't need to collect: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1a205ec09469b84f449ffb3703cb5c10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message could be a bit more helpful. The fundamental issue is that you're trying to hold references to the elements of `v` — the `req`s — but those elements don't exist anymore because you've consumed `v` (and therefore its elements) by calling `v.into_iter()`. What the compiler is trying to say is that in `v.into_iter().map(|req| ...)`, `req` is an owned `Request`, but the `Future`s you're producing and collecting into `futs` hold references to that owned data. When `map`’s closure ends, `req` is dropped (because it's owned, because of `into_iter()`), and then those `Future`s would be holding dangling references, which the compiler rightly prevents.

If you replace this with `v.iter()`, it will work because the `Future`s you've collected now hold references to data that still exists; nothing has been consumed.

Comment: For my understanding, could this also work if you define the method as `pub async fn do_req(self, num: i32) -> i32`, without the `&self`? Assuming this could work because then the future takes over ownership of the `req` variable, and can ensure that it lives long enough?

Comment: @flakes Yes, this should also work.